# eclipselink jpa 2.0 with j2se swing application freezing

Tags: swing, jpa, connection, eclipselink, freeze

how to configure eclipselink to use it inside swing application to connect to a database sever directly inside workgroup environment . i am currently using this but my application is freezing after some transactions (after 20-30 transaction ) .
my persistence.xml is ,

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.0.0.1:3306/myhotel"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
```

i went through  thread dump it shows..

```
SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-10" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03143400 nid=0xbec in Object.wait() [0x052ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.acquireConnection(ConnectionPool.java:102)
    - locked <0x27d6d7e0> (a org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.allocateReadConnection(ServerSession.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:191)
.....................
```

also awt thread even became wainting state

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x02c6d400 nid=0xfcc in Object.wait() [0x033ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.acquireConnection(ConnectionPool.java:102)
```

please some body help me !!!

Comment: Could you your persistence related code?. It seems that you are not realeasing the connections that have been acquired..

Comment: EntityManagerFactory emf=  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dbpers");
       EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
       public void save(){ 
        em.getTransaction().begin();
       em.persist(em);
       em.getTransaction().commit();
   
}

Comment: i use a class level entitymanager . how do i release connection after i commit save and how do i open new entity manager do i have to create it from  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager() ;????

Comment: check that you have all code within try/catch blocks such that you are releasing your entitymanager and the transaction in a finally block so that if an exception is encountered anytime after begin() is called, the transaction still gets cleaned up.  Otherwise, the transaction could stay open, keeping a connection resource until it times out.  If the em is closed or a persistence exception occurs, it cannot continue to be used - you will need to get a new one using emf.createEntityManager();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default connection pool size is 32 connections.  If you have > 32 active transactions, then the next request will wait until a connection is released.  Are you calling close() on your EntityManager and commit() or rollback() on your transaction?

Include you full persistence.xml.

You can also configure the connection pool wait time to trigger an exception if the pool size is exceeded,

"eclipselink.jdbc.connections.wait-timeout" or "eclipselink.connection-pool.default.wait" (in 2.2)

or increase the size of the pool,

"eclipselink.jdbc.connections.max" or "eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" (in 2.2)